# Why is `position: fixed` relative to the document instead of viewport in this case?

Tags: html, css

I got a gallery with some kind of lightbox I created.
The lightbox is `position:fixed` and `top:0`. So, if I'm right, it should be at the same position, no matter if I scroll down or not. Unfortunately that's not the case.

I can't reproduce the problem in a fiddle. You can check it out here: http://tobiasgla.us/portfolio. You can either open in on a mobile phone or use the device toolbar in Chrome.

The following 2 object got the `position:fixed` property, which isn't working:

```
.item-content{
   width: calc(100% - 100px);
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: 50px;
}
.dupe.dupAnim{
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:calc(100% - 100px);
   height:250px;
   margin:50px;
   position:fixed;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not that easy to recreate a problem if you use the exact same code, but the problem doesn't show up in a snippet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> When an ancestor has the `transform` or `perspective` property set to something other than none, that ancestor is used as the container instead of the viewport

Your `<div class="container">` uses an animation which includes `transform: translateY(...)`, which fits the exception listed in the documentation. For this reason, your `fixed` element is relative to the main container, which does indeed scroll with the page.

Comment: Thanks alot, I didn't know about that. Solved my problem :)